# How can I use a string as a class name in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry, this is so stupid and I cannot figure it out.

I have some code

This is the class name I am using and want to look for and define a variable for it:

`var pingid = 876567 // this number is calculated from other code but irrelevant for this question so I just put in the result of 876567 as that is what is returned`

I then want to use that class to add a class called `hidden` to all instances of where that class appears. So I use

`$(pingid).addClass('hidden');`

It won't work though. I know the normal way of defining a class is `$('.class')` above but thought I could just use the var I defined above with the class name.

I am going to kick myself when I find out what is missing but looking for some help.

Thanks

Comment: try $('.' + pingid).addClass('hidden');

Comment: I am so stuuuupid thank you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just concatenate a dot:

```
var pingid = 876567;
$('.' + pingid).addClass('hidden');
```

Comment: thank you - I hate it when it is the small things that have been messing with my head for over an hour :) cheers

Answer (score 3):

Prefix it with something other than numbers, e.g. `klass-`. Classes must start with a letter.

Edit: Okay, that wasn't the question, sorry. But my statement holds :)

Comment: hi - we uses classes in our project which are numerical e.g. `<div class='76547845784578'></div>` - This is due to dynamic nature of elements. The classes work as identifiers for tagreting, but we don't try and style them or use them in CSS like `.76547845784578` I assume it is ok to use numerical classes in our case or is there some reason why they must start with a letter no matter what? thanks for the input

Comment: It's the same as with multiple identical IDs in a document: It may work fine for you, it's just not standard-conform. And that you might experience the hard way some day, or not. :)